# Difference between two Dataframes with different size in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have to do the difference between two Dataframes with difference size. My code is :

```
index = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((348, 128))) 


for i in range(0, 128) : 

     index[i] = np.random.choice(range(435) , size = 348, replace = False) 

     index[i] = sorted(index[i])

z = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((435, 128))) 

for j in range(0, 128) : 

    for i in range(0,435) : 

        z[j][i] = i

out = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((87, 128)))

for in range(0, 128) :
    for j in range(0, 348) :
        for k in range(0, 435) :
            for l in range(0, 87) :
                if z[i][k] != index[i][j] :
                    out[i][l] = z[i][k]
```

I do this but it is too long for give me an answer. Do you have a more simple code to do the same thing ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Valeur is a list of 128 elements and each element is a DataFrame (435, 1). But  you can replace (len(Valeur)) by 435. I would like somehing like : index = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] and z = [[1, 2], [5, 6]]. The result will be zz = [[3], [4]].

Comment: I edit my code.  I would like to have a DataFrame at the out of my code. This Dataframe will be all the values in z that they're not in index. and it will be arrange in ascending order. I'm sorry because I'm not good in english and in Python.

Comment: if you use the code that i put up, you will see the two DataFrame that I use.  maybe the solution is to keep the first column in z and compare it to the first column in index dans see the difference. and do it again and again for every columns. and after recreate a Dataframe with all the new column create with the difference of z and index. but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: The first DataFrame's size is (435, 128), the second is (348,128) and the output is (87, 128). It's the difference between the first and the second DataFrame ( 435 - 348 = 87). And for 128 columns.